# How to convert InputStream to video file(avi)

Tags: java, hadoop

I have video files on HDFS with size 50MB each(1000 files). I want to take advantage and need processing of video as hadoop map reduce tasks. However i know only structured data to process like text files etc. I dont know how to process video files. 
I want on cluster i read all video files in the mapper and then convert that video into Image.Here i have to apply some graphics on Image and again i will convert this in the video back as a final output on HDFS . I am using Xuggler to do video to image and image to video conversion on hadoop cluster.

Could some one please suggest what job configuration i should use to achieve this?

Comment: it seems you have http link for video e.g. http://..../test.avi  so you can open stream and and create a file in local dir copy stream in local file and save file with .avi

Comment: the file is on HDFS on Amazon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input stream is the content of an AVI file, you could simply save the input stream to a file. That's your AVI then. You could write code along these lines (uses auto closables from JDK7 and IOUtils from apache commons):

```
void save(InputStream in, String fname) throws IOException {
    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(fname))) {
        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
    }
}
```

Comment: whats IOUtils? I can't find this.

Comment: As I said "IOUtils from Apache Commons": `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils`

Comment: Or come up with your own version. It's not that complicated if you take a look at the source.

Comment: Ahh Okay. thanks for this :)